# Golang distroless image throws stat VERSION error

Tags: docker, go, distroless

I am attempting to create a distroless docker image to put my golang binary on but whenever I run it (system is running PopOS 22.04) I get the following error:

`2023/11/25 16:58:50 stat VERSION: no such file or directory`

I have changed the final layer to an alpine image so I can shell into it and ensure that the binary is being copied over and can even execute it, however it does not run run with the given `ENTRYPOINT`. Can someone please help me figure out what is going on? Thanks!

Build:

```bash
docker build -t mkm29/gocloak:0.2.2-alpha.7 -f Dockerfile  .
```

Run:

```bash
docker run --rm mkm29/gocloak:0.2.2-alpha.7 help
```

When I only use the build image (and set the `ENTRYPOINT`) I do get my help output:

```bash
docker run --rm smigula/gocloak:0.2.2-alpha.8 help                             
gocloak

2023/11/25 21:41:27 Debugging enabled
2023/11/25 21:41:27 Checking variables
Usage:
  gocloak [flags]
  gocloak [command]

Available Commands:
  completion  Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  exportRealm Export a realm from Keycloak
  help        Help about any command
  version     Print the version number of gocloak
...
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```bash
# Build the binary
ARG BASE_REGISTRY=<NEXUS_URL>
ARG TARGETOS=linux
ARG TARGETARCH=amd64
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ARG GO_VERSION
ARG VERSION
ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG BUILD_PLATFORM="${TARGETOS}/${TARGETARCH}"
ARG MAINTAINER

FROM ${BASE_REGISTRY}/ironbank/google/golang/golang-1.20:1.20.0 as builder
LABEL git-revision=${GIT_COMMIT} \
      version=${VERSION} \
      build-date=${BUILD_DATE} \
      build-platform=${BUILD_PLATFORM} \
      maintainer=${MAINTAINER} \
      go-version=${GO_VERSION}
WORKDIR /workspace
# Copy the Go Modules manifests
COPY go.mod go.mod
# COPY go.sum go.sum
# cache deps before building and copying source so that we don't need to re-download as much
# and so that source changes don't invalidate our downloaded layer
RUN go mod download

# Copy the go source
COPY . .

# Build
# the GOARCH has not a default value to allow the binary be built according to the host where the command
# was called. For example, if we call make docker-build in a local env which has the Apple Silicon M1 SO
# the docker BUILDPLATFORM arg will be linux/arm64 when for Apple x86 it will be linux/amd64. Therefore,
# by leaving it empty we can ensure that the container and binary shipped on it will have the same platform.
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=${TARGETOS:-linux} GOARCH=${TARGETARCH:-amd64} go build -a -o gocloak main.go
#ENV PATH=$PATH:/workspace
#ENTRYPOINT ["/workspace/gocloak"]

# Use distroless as minimal base image to package the manager binary
# Refer to https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless for more details
# FROM ${BASE_REGISTRY}/ironbank/google/distroless/base:nonroot

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian12:nonroot AS final-image
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ARG GO_VERSION
ARG VERSION
ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG BUILD_PLATFORM
ARG MAINTAINER
LABEL git-revision=${GIT_COMMIT} \
      version=${VERSION} \
      build-date=${BUILD_DATE} \
      build-platform=${BUILD_PLATFORM} \
      maintainer=${MAINTAINER} \
      go-version=${GO_VERSION}
COPY --chown=65532:65532 --from=builder /workspace/gocloak .
USER 65532:65532

ENTRYPOINT ["/gocloak"]
```

Comment: Please include the command you are using to build and run the image, along with their output.

Comment: You didn't include the command that generates the error. And it looks like this is related to your application, so you'll need to include a [mcve] of your application that would generate that output.

Comment: `stat VERSION` suggests to me that the application code is looking for a file named `VERSION`; does that match something in your source code?  You'd need to make sure that gets copied into the final image.

Comment: This Dockerfile includes the COPY VERSION . line after the binary build step, ensuring that the VERSION file is present in the distroless image.

Make sure that the VERSION file is indeed required by your gocloak binary and that it's being used in a way that makes sense for your application.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This was some old code that I ended up having to pretty much completely refactor, I was hoping I did not have to do that. What was bugging me was that it ran when only using the builder image, and that image has a good number of high severity vulnerabilities. The VERSION file is needed when running the version subcommand, my suspicion is either it did not have the correct privileges (65532:65532) but more than likely the code needed to be refactored. All works find in the distroless image now.